# I keep getting KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, keyboardinterrupt

Can someone tell me why when I type the following in PyCharm I get:

```
if name == 'main': 
    n = int(raw_input()) 
    arr = list(set(map(int, raw_input().split()))) 
    arr.sort() 
    print arr[-2]
```

I've tried many different indentations, I'm just using this one as an example because it's the one I got on HackerRank

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/MacBookAir/PycharmProjects/excercises/exercise.py", line 3, in 
>       n = int(input())
>   KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: from collections import Counter
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    arr = list(set(map(int, raw_input().split())))
    arr.sort()
    print arr[-2]

*** I've tried many different indentations, I'm just using this one as an example because it's the one I got on HackerRank ***

Comment: Please add the above comment in the post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks weird:

```
if name == 'main'
```

Should be:

```
if __name__=="__main__"
```